# Create a file object from a path

Tags: javascript

I am using a library which has this in the documentantion:

> opentype.parse(buffer)
>
> Parse an ArrayBuffer containing OpenType font data

When I try to pass as a parameter the URL location of my file, it seems to fail and throws this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: First argument to DataView constructor must be an
>   ArrayBuffer

From what I understand this function expects something like a File Object. How can I make this work with just the file path which is located in my app's root directory?

Comment: Can you say the name of that library?

Comment: I would assume it's https://github.com/nodebox/opentype.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var opentype = require('opentype.js');
var fs = require('fs');

function toArrayBuffer(buffer) {
    var ab = new ArrayBuffer(buffer.length);
    var view = new Uint8Array(ab);
    for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
        view[i] = buffer[i];
    }
    return ab;
}

fs.readFile('font.otf', function(err, buffer) {
  if (err) throw errr;

  var font = opentype.parse(toArrayBuffer(buffer));

  console.log(font); // this is a Font object

});
```

Note that you will get the same result using the load method:

```
opentype.load('font.otf', function (err, font) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(font); // this is a Font object
});
```